# how to show value without clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using html5 and javascript .I am reading excel file from java script and showing output..PLease analyze my code first

```
 <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="readdata(1, 2)" value="Submit" />
```

```
var xVal = 1;
var yVal = 2

    function readdata(x,y) {
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
        try {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.Visible = false;
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
            var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
            var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
            //alert(data);
            drawWithexcelValue(data);
            xVal = xVal + 1;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
```

Now I'm reading the file from this code and showing the output with this code:

```
function drawWithexcelValue(val) {

    var txtSpeed = val; //alert(txtSpeed.value);
    if (txtSpeed !== null) {

        iTargetSpeed = txtSpeed;

        // Sanity checks
        if (isNaN(iTargetSpeed)) {
            iTargetSpeed = 0;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed < 0) {
            iTargetSpeed = 0;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed > 80) {
            iTargetSpeed = 80;
        }

        job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
    }
}
```

Q .1 every time i click on the submit button it show me the value from excel file ,i want that i didn't have to click every time on submit button ..it automatically show the values at some time interval for say 4 seconds.

Q :-2  I didn't want the submit button ,that means  when i run this code it automaticaly start running the script  say  onload ="readdata(1, 2)" ,but it is showing only one value ...how to show all values with some time interval ..please help!!!!!

Guys if you can give me edited code than it really will be help full for me

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here this code will surely work for ya

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Speedometer HTML5 Canvas</title>

    <script src="script copy.js">

</script>

</head>
<body onload='draw(0);'>
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="440" height="220">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>
    <div id="divHidden" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px">
        <form id="drawTemp">
        <input type="text" id="txtSpeed" name="txtSpeed" value="20" maxlength="2" />
        <input type="button" value="Draw" onclick="drawWithInputValue();">
        <input type="file" id="file" onchange="checkfile(this);" />
       <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="readdata(1, 2)" value="Submit" /> 


    <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop Meter</button>


        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    var myVar=setInterval(function(){readdata(1,2)},2000);
    function myStopFunction()
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }


    function checkfile(sender) {
        var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls", ".csv");
        var fileExt = sender.value;
        fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
        if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
            alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
               validExts.toString() + " types.");
            return false;
        }
        else return true;

    }
var xVal = 1;
var yVal = 2

    function readdata(x,y) {
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
        try {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.Visible = false;
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
            var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
            var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
            //alert(data);
            drawWithexcelValue(data);
            xVal = xVal + 1;
            if(data==null || data=="")
            { 
            myStopFunction(); 
            }
            excel.Application.Quit();
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    }
</script>
```